# Import SCSS with Typescript, React and Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I want to import .scss classes and apply it to the `className` property of a React component.

My project tree is as follow :

```
root/
  ...
  config/
    ...
    webpack.config.js
  src/
    ...
    global.d.ts
    app/
      ...
      components/
        layout/
          ...
          Box/
            Box.scss
            Box.tsx
```

.d.ts file  :

```js
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: { [className: string]: string }
  export = content
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
...
module: {
    rules: [
      // assets (.css, .scss)
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i, // s[ac]ss
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      // typescript
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: path.resolve(rootPath, 'node_modules'),
      },
    ],
  },
...
```

Box.scss

```
.Box {
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ede9f9;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #47b0b0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Box.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import * as styles from './Box.scss'

type BoxProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const Box = ({ children }: BoxProps) => <div className={styles.Box}>{children}</div>

export default Box
```

`console.log(styles.Box)` prints `undefined`. What I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I have never heard of importing scss into the project itself.

Isn't scss only meant for easier styling that will then be compiled to normal css?

I have style.scss and style.css

In npm, I use "sass --watch style.scss style.css".
This compiles style.scss into style.css every time you save the style.scss file.

Then just import style.css normally into your react application